# Why are all primes squared less one a multiple of 24, but not also a multiple of 12?

Tags: prime-numbers, prime-gaps

So I can't wrap my head around this problem from numberphile (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZMkIiFs35HQ&t=28s).

Why does this work for multiples of 24 but not 12?

Comment: Well if $p^2-1=24x$ and $x=2y$, then $p^2-1=12y.$ Also you should specify that $p \gt 3.$

Comment: What @MohammadZuhairKhan is saying is that it does work for multiples of 12 as well.

Comment: Right, so why not say "All prime numbers squared are one more than a multiple of 12?"....Why choose 24 over 12? Does 24 more concisely demonstrate the statement? Or does 12 fail at some point where 24 does not?

Comment: @H.Halv Because using $24$ is the stronger statement. All multiples of $24$ plus one are also multiples of $12$ plus one. But not all multiples of $12$ plus one are multiples of $24$ plus one (for instance, $13$).

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan, I think you meant to say $y=2x$, not $x=2y$.

Comment: @BarryCipra Sorry for the typographical error.

Comment: @kccu Thanks!!!

Comment: It also works for multiples of $1$ – all primes squared are one more than a multiple of $1$ – but it's kinda stupid to say that, when you can say $24$ instead of $1$. Same thing applies (though not to such an extreme) for saying $24$ instead of $12$.

Comment: You can, if you like, say that $12$ is a common divisor for all numbers of the form $p^2-1$ with $p$ a prime greater than $3$, while $24$ is the *greatest* common divisor for all those numbers. (Note, $p$ doesn't really need to be a prime, it just needs to be an odd number not divisible by $3$.)